# Azure AD using Visual Studio Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I created an MVC application using visual studio 2013 and connected to our Azure AD Tenant with no issues. All of a sudden this morning i'm getting error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Tenants'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Tenants'. The duplicate key value is (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX).
The statement has been terminated.

The Tenant key is our organization's Tenant Id.

This application has been in development for over a month with no issues until this morning.

The error occurs in this function that was generated when the application was created:

```
public static void RefreshKeys(string metadataLocation)
    {
        IssuingAuthority issuingAuthority = ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.GetIssuingAuthority(metadataLocation);

        bool newKeys = false;
        foreach (string thumbprint in issuingAuthority.Thumbprints)
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(thumbprint))
            {
                newKeys = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (newKeys)
        {
            using (TenantDbContext context = new TenantDbContext())
            {
                context.IssuingAuthorityKeys.RemoveRange(context.IssuingAuthorityKeys);
                foreach (string thumbprint in issuingAuthority.Thumbprints)
                {
                    context.IssuingAuthorityKeys.Add(new IssuingAuthorityKey { Id = thumbprint });
                }
                foreach (string issuer in issuingAuthority.Issuers)
                {
                    context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant { Id = issuer.TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Last() });
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating new Tenants without first checking if they already exist. At a guess, the system has never before dealt with a Tenant ID that is associated with more than one IssuingAuthority.

To resolve the immediate issue, check if the Tenant already exists, like this (note I haven't tested this code):

```
public static void RefreshKeys(string metadataLocation)
{
    IssuingAuthority issuingAuthority = ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.GetIssuingAuthority(metadataLocation);

    bool newKeys = false;
    foreach (string thumbprint in issuingAuthority.Thumbprints)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(thumbprint))
        {
            newKeys = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (newKeys)
    {
        using (TenantDbContext context = new TenantDbContext())
        {
            context.IssuingAuthorityKeys.RemoveRange(context.IssuingAuthorityKeys);
            foreach (string thumbprint in issuingAuthority.Thumbprints)
            {
                context.IssuingAuthorityKeys.Add(new IssuingAuthorityKey { Id = thumbprint });
            }

            // Get the Tenant IDs we have been supplied with
            IEnumerable<string> tenantIds = issuingAuthority.Issuers.Select(i => i.TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Last());

            // Exclude any that already exist in the database
            List<string> newTenantIds = tenantIds.Except(context.Tenants.Select(t => t.Id)).ToList();

            // Add only the new Tenant instances to the database
            foreach (string tenantId in newTenantIds)
            {
                context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant { Id = tenantId });
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix the issue. Any Idea why that would have just started randomly happening?

Comment: @KevinKulla The code assumed that the tenant ID was always unique and would never be reused, since it always performed an insert into the Tenants table. This appears not to be the case - perhaps tenant IDs have wrapped around some upper limit and are now being reused?